# TestCase not found in KernelTestCase.php with Symfony 3.2.7

Tags: php, git, symfony, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm having problems when running Symfony (PHPUnit integrated) tests in my server, it works as expected in my build host but when I upload them to Gitlab CI via Git it throws me the next error:

> Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in /project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php on line 24

I tried executing `phpunit`, `phpunit .`, `phpunit tests` all with the same results

It was working until a few weeks ago.

My server Symfony version is 3.2.7 and the PHPUnit version is 4.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit version is 4.2.6 is **very** old, and does not contain any Namespaced classes.  The Symfony KernelTestCase.php now uses those PHPUnit namespaces to pull on the TestCase class.

There is forward compatibility in PHPUnit 5.4.3, though v5.7, if not 6.0 would be better.

So, you'll want to upgrade your composer.json file and tests to use the new namespaces.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to update the Composer file later when I'm in front of my build host and I'll let you know.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a PHPUnit version problem in the build host I have PHPUnit 5.x. Now I need to change the integrated PHPUnit for a composer-managed one, but this is a different topic. Thank you very much